# How to calculate Primes number

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve programming question, a term called "FiPrima". The "FiPrima" number is the sum of prime numbers before, until the intended prime tribe.

INPUT FORMAT
The first line is an integer number n. Then followed by an integer number x for n times.

OUTPUT FORMAT
Output n number of rows. Each row must contain the xth "FiPrima" number of each line.

```
INPUT EXAMPLE

5
1 2 3 4 5

OUTPUT EXAMPLE
2
5
10
17
28

EXPLANATION
The first 5 prime numbers in order are 2, 3, 5, 7 and 13.

So:

The 1st FiPrima number is 2 (2)
The 2nd FiPrima number is 5 (2 + 3)
The 3rd FiPrima number is 10 (2 + 3 + 5)
The 4th FiPrima number is 17 (2 + 3 + 5 + 7)
The 5th FiPrima number is 28 (2 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 13)
CONSTRAINTS
1 ≤ n ≤ 100
1 ≤ x ≤ 100
```

Can anyone create the code ?

Comment: ***Can anyone create the code ?*** That usually is not how StackOverflow works. The requirement is you show your attempt first (even the broken code) and we help fix it.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes